# Would that be possible to resize the background-image based on the properties and attributes of the anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, anchor, background-image

I have an anchor tag that displays an image:

```
 <a href="#" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; background: url(computer.jpg); position: absolute;"></a>
```

Would that be possible to resize the background-image based on the properties and attributes of the anchor tag? e.g. set the width and height of the background image to 300px.

(Please don't suggest putting an img tag inside the  tag as that's not the question...)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Would a background-size work with background-norepeat specified?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```
<a href="#" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; background: url(computer.jpg); background-size: 300px 300px; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;"></a>
```

Comment: It's CSS3, so YMMV depending on what browsers you want to target. "The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+."

Comment: thanks, yes but it only works in IE 9.0 as selbie said. how could it be achieved with CSS 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's feasible using css2 without some javascript but as selbie said There is a CSS3 property that do it quite nicely:

```
     -moz-background-size: 100% 100%; /* FF3.6 */
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; /* Saf3-4 */
          background-size: 100% 100%; /* Opera, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4 */
```

Another option is to use img tag:

In your HTML:

```
<img id="background" src="images/computer.jpg" alt="" />
```

In your CSS:

```
#background {position:absolute; z-index:1; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

**Update:**

Have a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/766-how-to-resizeable-background-image/) by chris coyer.

Comment: thanks; how using javascript and anchor tag you could achieve that?! as mentioned the img tag solution wasn't the question...